# SQL sort records which have many to many relations in alphabetical order

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sorting, many-to-many

I have following db tables: **COMMENT** and **TAG** and **COMMENT_TAG**. There is many to many relation between them, actually single comment can have multiple tags and single tags can be used in multiple comments. Let's imagine following:

```
COMMENT
---------------
ID      TEXT
1       comment1
2       comment2
3       comment3
4       comment4


TAG
---------------
ID      NAME
1       bb
2       cc
3       ca
4       aa
5       ac
6       bd


COMMENT_TAG
---------------
ID_COMMENT      ID_TAG
1               1
1               2
1               3
1               4
2               1
2               3
3               3
3               4
3               5
3               6
4               1
4               2
4               3
4               4
4               5
4               6
```

As result of this on FE side following data is shown

```
Comment     Tags
==================================
comment1    bb, cc, ca, aa
comment2    bb, ca
comment3    ca, aa, ac, bd
comment4    bb, cc ,ca, aa, ac, bd
```

I would like to make a sort in following way:

**1** Sort tags per each comment in alphabetical order:

```
Comment     Tags
==================================
comment1    aa, bb, ca, cc
comment2    bb, ca
comment3    aa, ac, bd, ca
comment4    aa, ac, bb, bd, ca, cc
```

**2** Sort comments by tags in alphabetical order:

```
Comment     Tags
==================================
comment4    aa, ac, bb, bd, ca, cc
comment3    aa, ac, bd, ca
comment1    aa, bb, ca, cc
comment2    bb, ca
```

Could you please advice the way how it can be achieved with SQL or advice some alternative ways of sorting for such use case?

Comment: Tag the question with the database that you use.

Comment: @forpas sorry forgot about this. I've just added labels

Comment: SQL Server is not the same as Oracle. In fact you must not only tag the database that you use but also its version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the tables and group by comment.
Then use a function like [`LISTAGG()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) for Oracle 11g+, to concatenate all the tags for each comment:

```
select c.text, listagg(t.name, ',') within group (order by t.name) tags
from "COMMENT" c
left join COMMENT_TAG ct on ct.id_comment = c.id
left join TAG t on t.id = ct.id_tag
group by c.id, c.text
```

Add the `ORDER BY` clause for each case:

```
order by c.text
```

or:

```
order by tags
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=947762236b6681d62bc8c4c4d8af1e78).